# beamer: How to add a new option for the frame environment

Tags: beamer

In some frame I want the title rotated at the left side of the frame. This happens more frequent in 16x9 formats.

How can I redefine the frame environment to add an option, that allows me to do that.
If this new option is not used, the original frame behavior is applied.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[rotatetitle]
  \frametitle{My Rotated Title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It could also be an option to the \frametitle{} command.

While I could solve this particular issue with a new variant of the \frametitle command (which I am doing now), I have several optinal frame behaviors in mind, that I would like to switch on and off with options. Examples are: make the textwidth wider and suppress the foot line. So I am looking for a general mechanism to add options and optional behavior to the \frame environment, while still keeping all the default behavior and existing options such as fragile.
What would such a mechanism be?

--Axel

Answer (score 2):

You could use the same technique as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1163#a1370

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{regular}{\insertframetitle}
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{rotated}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[rotate=90,anchor=north east] at (current page.north west) {\insertframetitle};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\makeatletter
\providebool{rotatedframe}
\define@key{beamerframe}{rotated}[true]{
  \booltrue{rotatedframe}
  \begingroup
  \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[rotated]
}

\apptocmd{\beamer@reseteecodes}{%
  \ifbool{rotatedframe}{%
    \endgroup
    \boolfalse{rotatedframe}
  }{}
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{normal title}
This page shall have the regular frametitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[rotated]
\frametitle{rotated title}
This page shall have the special frametitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{normal title}
This page shall have the regular frametitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```